# Converting datetime format without using SAP RFC with C#

Tags: c#, datetime, saprfc

I got a problem when trying to convert a date-time format with SAP RFC.

I'm trying this:

```
string tmpDate = argDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpDate);

IRfcFunction SAPRateAPI = null;
SAPRateAPI = _ecc.Repository.CreateFunction("ZRFC_CUST_CONDITION_RATE");

SAPRateAPI = CreateSAPRateAPI(SAPRateAPI, argPartnerSAPTranCode, argCustSAPTranCode, argMaterialCode, date);
SAPRateAPI.Invoke(_ecc);
```

But getting an error 'Specified Cast is not valid'

Comment: Which line you get the exception? Seems like that CreateSAPRateAPI method receives a DateTime not an string, so why do you need to convert the date into string?

Comment: i'm receiving date in 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm: tt ' format getting when i trying to invoke rfc

Comment: You appear to be converting from a date `argDate` to a string `tmpDate` and then back to a date `date`. Can you explain?

Comment: You could have stated that argDate is a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
  // Parse date and time with custom specifier.
  string format = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:tt";
  DateTime date;
  try {
     date = DateTime.ParseExact(argDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
  catch (FormatException e) {
     throw new ArgumentException("argDate", e);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime in C# has its own representation and doesn't has any "format" which you can see or change.

So phrase "datetime in dd.mm.yyyy format" has no sense at all.

Let's look at your code:

```
string tmpDate = argDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpDate);
```

Here you're converting `DateTime` to `string` and then back to `DateTime`.

You're getting exception on back cast just because `Convert` uses your windows specified culture, and in the case it differs from the one in the string - you need `DateTime.ParseExact` and explicit format specification.

But even if this cast will be successful - you again will get `DateTime` and this two lines will not change its format.

It looks like all you need - is just pass date only part of datetime as argument of your function. But it can be achieved pretty easily without any casts just by using `argDate.Date` (assuming `agrDate` is DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime( argDate.Years, argDate.Month, argDate.Day );
```

I think this is what you want.

See: [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit:**

Which is the same as Andy Korneyev solution - Ok, his is nicer too look at, but both create a second `DateTime` object.

Comment: This looks like unnecessary new object creation. Since argDate *already* is DateTime, `argDate.Date` is pretty enough and it does the same job.

Comment: Depends - if for some reason no hour/minute/second info is allowed then you have to do something. And it sure is faster then tostring/parse ;-)

Comment: Where did I mentioned "to string/parse"? Have you read my comment? `argDate.Date` returns the same as `new DateTime( argDate.Years, argDate.Month, argDate.Day )` - date only part of `argDate`, so there is no reason to create a new `DateTime` object.

Comment: Sorry, only two coffees yet... You are right - but I do believe that .Date does the same as my code explicitely does. So I think the performance should be the same, but of course it is better from a clean-code perspective